# NSUserDefaults doubts

Tags: iphone, twitter, nsuserdefaults, sharing

```
#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterControllerDelegate
- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {
    NSLog(@"Authenicated for %@", username);
    [_btnTwitter setTitle:username forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I have this code for displaying username for twitter ,and it works well,but when i navigate to another page and came back the title username of the button disappears,i know we have to set a NSUserDefault value in viewwillapper for checking the username exists or not.But i didn't know how to handle the nSUserDefault,if anyone have an idea to solve this issue please help me.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //Sets up the NSUserDefaults
    //Sets up the NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //Checks if there is a saved User Name    
    if([defaults objectForKey:@"kTwitterUserName"])
        NSString *username = [defaults objectForKey:@"kTwitterUserName"];
      [_btnTwitter setTitle:username forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
    {

    }
```

this is how my viewwillappear lokks
and

```
- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {
    NSLog(@"Authenicated for %@", username);
    [_btnTwitter setTitle:username forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:username forKey:@"kTwitterUserName"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    }
```

this is how my twitermethod looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserDefaults are very simple to work with.  They are kind of like a dictionary, you set an object and a key.  So to do what your trying to do, you can use something like the following:

```
//This just sets up the defaults - similar to allocating a dictionary
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Then to set an object in your defaults, you set an object/key pair like this:

```
[defaults setObject:username forKey:@"kTwitterUserName"];
```

It is important to call this method at some point: `[defaults synchronize];`.  This explicitly saves the defaults.  So you might as well do it immediately after you set the username key.

Then to read the saved username:

```
 NSString *username = [defaults objectForKey:@"kTwitterUserName"];
```

Your oAuth Method should look like this:

```
- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {
     //Any thing else you want to do - NSLogs, etc.

     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setObject:username forKey:@"kTwitterUserName"];
     [defaults synchronize];
}
```

So your `viewWillAppear` will look something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Sets up the NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //Checks if there is a saved User Name    
     if([defaults objectForKey:@"kTwitterUserName"]) {
         NSString *username = [defaults objectForKey:@"kTwitterUserName"];
    } else
        //Do something else because there is no saved username
        NSLog(@"no username saved");
}
```

Let me know in a comment if you need any clarification.

Comment: That looks right, but its kind of hard to read in a comment.  That should do it for you.  But make sure to change `@"theUserName"` to `username `.

Comment: `theusername ` was just an example I was using to show you how it works, for your specific case, use `username` as the object.

Comment: Great.  glad to help.  check out the new section I just added to my answer, that should make it even more clear

Comment: Sorry about that.  I made a minor syntax error.  I just posted a correct version

Comment: And username is a new variable I decleared in `viewWillAppear` so you can get use the users name in your code, or set a button title or whatever.  It is a brand new variable.

Comment: Instead of declaring it in the if statement, declare it in the .h file.

Comment: i have one more question ,i posted it,if u have time please look into it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240972/touchevent-doubts-in-iphone.thnks.sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: I checked it out and I'm not really good with animations.  I also was a little confused about what you were asking.  So i don't think I can help.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in the aspect you'll want to save this somehow, and NSUserDefaults will work fine for this.  Save and read samples are below:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"username" forKey:@"UsersUsername"];

// reading an NSString
NSString *theString = [prefs stringForKey:@"UsersUsername"];
```

Comment: but which of the above code has to be put in viewwillapperar method?

Comment: You save the username like shown above whenever you retrieve their username.  And then whenever you want to access it to read it again, i.e. - in the viewWillAppear, you can read it as shown above and assign whichever NSString or UI element text to that.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/ for more details