# How can we move a view vertically upward and downwards?

Tags: iphone, touch

I have a tableview in my main view, and I need to move this tableview vertically with touch.

I want to drag this tableview upwards and downwards when touching at any position, and when my finger moves upward or downward the tableview will move according to the touch.

I have lots of controllers in my main view, so i want to touch the tableview only.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

How do I use these delegates in the question above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think a little googling would give you the answer quicker

Answer (score 4):

YOu just make a class , inherited from UITableview

Make a class Drag

Drag.h should be like this

```
@interface Drag : UITableView { 
    CGPoint touchingPoint;
}
```

and Modify Drag.m File by including following methods

Drag.m

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{ 
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    touchingPoint = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];    
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{       
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];     
    [UITableView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UITableView setAnimationDuration:0.1];             
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y += pt.y - touchingPoint.y;    
    [self setFrame:newFrame];   
    [UITableView commitAnimations];     
}
```

That's it.

Moreover , in Your `viewDidLoad` method,

put these lines

```
Drag *objDrag = [[Drag alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];

objDrag.delegate = self;
objDrag.dataSource = self;
[objDrag setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];    

[self.view  addSubview:objDrag];
```

**Remember:** for dragging vertically , you must touch the separators of table otherwise it will consider touch to cell and will scroll instead of dragging.

Comment: Do you want it to ben moved automatically or moved by fingure. If you want it to move by fingure , its called drag , here Drag is nothing but the name of the Classs ,you may change it if you don't find it suitable for your coding reference

Answer (score 0):

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` can be used to create table  with tapping the view and getting the CGPoint of the view and after then setting the tableview frame with these coordinates.

Note:- It will be better to represent in User Interface if table drag is done with
`-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` with this function.

Comment: but how to set the tableview x and y axis accoridng to touch

Comment: get the point from the touches began touch event and used it as the frame of the table view . mytableView=[[UITableView alloc] initwithframe:CGRectMake(point.x,point.y,width,height)];  flow sequence  touchevent--->[self drawTable:point]--->inside method set the frame of table